# How can I add log messages to SVN without committing any files?

Tags: svn

Is it possible add a new log message to SVN without having to commit a file?

If not, what workarounds would you suggest, e.g. committing a one-byte hidden file?

Comment: Why does it have to be in the SVN log files?

Comment: Because the SVN log files are stored very efficiently and I want to maintain the open standard. You are correct that normally, I could use a flat text file or database, but I want people to be able to use SVN LOG to get a status update from the command line.

Comment: *but I want people to be able to use SVN LOG to get a status update from the command line*: which status do you want to update when you don't change anything in your files?

Answer (score 11):

Instead of changing and committing an actual dummy file, you can consider changing metadata (aka property) of a directory.  Such kind of metadata is something tracked by SVN and hence, can trigger a commit even there is no change in any file.

For example, just create/change a property in the root directory and do the commit.  By doing so, user will not see any meaningless dummy file in the source, and will not see a meaningless file change entry of the dummy file either.

e.g.

```
> svn propset LOG_FOR_MESSAGE `date` .
> svn commit -m 'a commit without any file change'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use svnmucc to crate an empty commit.  Just tell it to delete a property on the root path that doesn't exist.  The root directory will end up showing as modified, but there won't be any actual changes.

```
$ svnadmin create repo

$ svnmucc -m "commit message" -U file://`pwd`/repo propdel nosuchproperty /
r1 committed by breser at 2013-08-21T03:34:00.270416Z

$ svn log -v --diff file://`pwd`/repo
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1 | breser | 2013-08-20 20:34:00 -0700 (Tue, 20 Aug 2013) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   M /

commit message


------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Cool trick.  Just in doubt, is it an expected behavior for SVN accepting such invalid propdel, or it is simply a bug that may be fixed in the future?

Comment: That's a good question, I'm not sure it's a bug.  I was originally trying to just add a property and then delete it in the same transaction since that should result in a noop.  But for some reason svnmucc elided the delete.  I haven't bothered to dig into it to see why.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the purpose. Why would I like to see dozens of log entries without a single file change?

You want the latest status of the repository? You can use *revision properties*. You can change a revision property without committing any file, and that revision property will be attached to the revision. Three special ones you are already familiar with: `svn:log`, `svn:date`, and `svn:author`. These are the commit message, the date of the commit, and the author of the change. What you see when you do a `svn log`.

However, you can create your own properties, and simply change them without a commit:

```
 $ svn ps site:status --rev-prop -rHEAD "Sunny" $REPO_URL
```

The only thing is you have to create a revision property change hook to allow you to change revision properties.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I found a workaround where you could modify a 1-byte file and commit it with a log message. While this is clearly a work-around, there seems to be no other way to get SVN to add a log to a unchanged file. I could be wrong about this.
To be clear, it may be possible if you use a custom SVN client, but I needed to use a standard command line client.